# Referring to interaction trigger control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am using IController interface to bind action handlers to control properties like this:

```
<TextBox Name="FirstNameTextBox" Margin="5" Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
    MinWidth="200">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=GetBindingCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FirstNameTextBox}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```

I need to pass an evoking control to handler, so I do in with

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FirstNameTextBox}"
```

This works fine and does it's job, but I need to specify each control by name and repeat almost the same code of trigger setting for each control. If there is a way to refer to a control from trigger, I could have made a resource and share it for every control, but I didn't find one. So this is the question: can I somehow refer to a control from the trigger without specifying a name?

**Update**

Ok, I've found a solution for this. You have "just" define your own TriggerAction like this

```
class SenderAccessTrigger : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        if(AssociatedObject!=null && Command!=null)
        {
            Command.Execute(AssociatedObject);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(SenderAccessTrigger), new UIPropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(SenderAccessTrigger), new UIPropertyMetadata());
}
```

The thing is that TriggerAction class has an AssociatedObject property, which is actually the control, evoking the event. But this property is private. So to gain access to it I've defined my own TriggerAction, which executes the Command with this AssociatedObject as a parameter.

Now in xaml instead of

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=GetBindingCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FirstNameTextBox}"/>
```

I can do

```
<local:SenderAccessTrigger Command="{Binding Path=GetBindingCommand}"/>
```

and get an evoking control as a parameter in a Command.

But there is another problem. Interaction.Triggers appeared to be not a dependency property, so one can not assign a resource to it. So I still have to repeat the same code for every control I want to assign this command to.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Comment: Оh, no, of course I tride that. It sends to function as a parameter not the control, but InvokeCommandAction object. And Relative Source Ancestor Type FindAncestor does not work too. But actually I found a soluton, but there still is another problem.